# Matplotlib Toolbar Takes Up Too Much Space When Resizing

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, resize, toolbar

I have this application that shows stock prices. I would like the graph to take as much space as it possibly can when resizing. However, for some reason, the toolbar always takes lots of space. Right now when I expand the window, it looks like this.
[image]

I want the top part to be a bit thinner leaving just enough room for the toolbar. I tried giving a smaller height to the toolbar frame but it did not help. Any input is appreciated.

Here is the relevant code:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
global timeFrameCount
global coy
global firm
global timeTrack

def __init__(self,master=None):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.createWidgets()

def createWidgets(self):

    self.plotbutton=ttk.Button(master=root, text="APPLY/RESET", command=lambda: self.plot(),width=12)
    self.plotbutton.grid(row=3,columnspan=2,sticky='s')
    self.entry=ttk.Entry(master=root,width=10)
    self.entry.grid(row=2,columnspan=2,sticky='s')
def plot(self):
    global firm
    global coy
    global timeTrack
    firm=True
    timeTrack=False
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5))
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 1), (0, 0), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
    ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 1), (4, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)
    ax1.tick_params(bottom="off", left="off")
    ax2.tick_params(bottom="off", left="off")
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, rowspan=1,columnspan=2,sticky='wens')
    toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(master=root,height=20)
    toolbar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='we')
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, toolbar_frame)
    toolbar.update()
root=tk.Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.iconbitmap('zzz.ico')
app=Application(master=root)
root.geometry('700x608')
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed the figure size and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving weight to row 1 instead of row 0. The weight should be on the row with the plot.